# C++: Trouble with ending a loop based on a condition?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops, conditional-statements

This code is used to run a loop three times, that takes the numbers of eggs gathered and outputs the number in dozens and extra until the user enters a negative number. Then, it prints out the average amount of eggs gathered (entered), and outputs the total number of dozens and extra.

The inputs we were assigned to use are:
43,
31,
-1,
24,
8,
14,
-999,
-5.

Everything is fine up until we input -5. Our teacher doesn't want the average or total number of dozens and extras to print (you'll see what I mean in the output).

The source code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int   eggNum;
    int   eggDozens;
    int   eggExtra;
    int   eggTotal;
    int   loopCount;
    int   forCount;
    float eggAvg;
    int   totalDozens;
    int   totalExtra;

    for(forCount = 1; forCount <= 3; forCount=forCount + 1)
    {
        cout << left << "TEST #" << forCount << ":" << endl;
        cout << "Welcome to Aunt Ellen\'s eggs to dozens converter!";
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "\tEnter the number of eggs gathered: ";
        cin  >> eggNum;

        eggTotal  = 0;
        loopCount = 0;

        while(eggNum >= 0)
        {
            eggDozens = eggNum / 12;
            eggExtra  = eggNum % 12;

            if(eggDozens != 0)
            {
                if(eggExtra != 0)
                {
                    cout << "\tYou have " << eggDozens << " dozen ";
                    cout << eggExtra << " eggs.";
                    cout << endl << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\tYou have " << eggDozens << " dozen eggs.";
                    cout << endl << endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\tYou have " << eggExtra << " eggs.";
                cout << endl << endl;
            }

            loopCount = loopCount + 1;
            eggTotal  = eggTotal + eggNum;

            cout << "\tEnter the number of eggs gathered: ";
            cin  >> eggNum;
        }
        cout << endl << "TOTALS:" << endl;
        eggAvg = eggTotal / float(loopCount);
        cout << "\tOn average " << eggAvg << " eggs have been";
        cout << " gathered.";

        totalDozens = eggTotal / 12;
        totalExtra  = eggTotal % 12;

        cout << endl << "\tA total of " << totalDozens << " dozen ";
        cout << totalExtra << " and eggs have been gathered!" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
TEST #1:
Welcome to Aunt Ellen's eggs to dozens converter!

    Enter the number of eggs gathered: 43
    You have 3 dozen 7 eggs.

    Enter the number of eggs gathered: 31
    You have 2 dozen 7 eggs.

    Enter the number of eggs gathered: -1

TOTALS:
    On average 37 eggs have been gathered.
    A total of 6 dozen 2 and eggs have been gathered!


TEST #2:
Welcome to Aunt Ellen's eggs to dozens converter!

    Enter the number of eggs gathered: 24
    You have 2 dozen eggs.

    Enter the number of eggs gathered: 8
    You have 8 eggs.

    Enter the number of eggs gathered: 14
    You have 1 dozen 2 eggs.

    Enter the number of eggs gathered: -999

TOTALS:
    On average 15.3333 eggs have been gathered.
    A total of 3 dozen 10 and eggs have been gathered!


TEST #3:
Welcome to Aunt Ellen's eggs to dozens converter!

    Enter the number of eggs gathered: -5

TOTALS:
    On average -1.#IND eggs have been gathered.
    A total of 0 dozen 0 and eggs have been gathered!
```

I don't want the very last "TOTALS" and the lines following. I want the program to terminate after entering -5.

Comment: @merlin2011 I set the condition that the loop is to end if the number entered is less than 0.

Comment: But your program is not terminating after the `-1` input either. Are you just trying to cut off the last TOTALS block?

Comment: @merlin2011 The WHILE-LOOP ends if you enter a negative number; however it's nested in a for loop that will run what's inside of the curly brackets three times. And yes. Perhaps I can do an if-statement that says if the average is less than zero, don't print the totals.

Comment: Yes, My answer allows you to always escape the *last* print, but if you want to not print whenever the average is negative, I'll update.

Comment: @merlin2011 Please do. We can't use break because we haven't learned it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to do this before entering the while loop:

```
cin  >> eggNum;

if (eggNum < 0)
    break ;
```

That will quit the `for` loop, and `return 0;`

You may, if you want to, add some comments to the caller about entering negative numbers before calling `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you only want to omit the *last* block of `TOTALS`.

You can simply add a special case to leave the outer loop early in this case.

Right before this block, but *after* the closing brace of the `while` loop.

```
cout << endl << "TOTALS:" << endl;
        eggAvg = eggTotal / float(loopCount);
```

Insert this:

```
if (forCount == 3) break;
```

If you just want to avoid printing whenever the average is less than `0`, then instead you should insert in the same location.

```
if (eggAvg < 0) continue;
```

This will skip the rest of that iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't include things we haven't learned yet, and break is one of them.

Comment: @user3517567, I hope you have learned `continue`. Another option is `goto`, but that is frowned upon.

Comment: We haven't learned those either. This is an introduction to CS class, so we're kind of just starting out with C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple answer to your problem would be to just put an if statement around the printing total code. Like this:

```
   if(eggNum > -5){ //won't print for negative 5

    cout << endl << "TOTALS:" << endl;
    eggAvg = eggTotal / float(loopCount);
    cout << "\tOn average " << eggAvg << " eggs have been";
    cout << " gathered.";

    totalDozens = eggTotal / 12;
    totalExtra  = eggTotal % 12;

    cout << endl << "\tA total of " << totalDozens << " dozen ";
    cout << totalExtra << " and eggs have been gathered!" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    }
```

I hope this helps!